# Creating rectangles from "ImageCorners" output

Tags: image-processing

I want to create multiple rectangle areas from this image
  [image: 45 squares]

where the rectangle would be defined by the points on the edges of the outer most squares - dont mind the inner ones. In the end there would be 45 rectangle areas.
I would then like to perform some tests whether there are certain spots of interest within the newly defined square areas (probably with a test if a point is in the convex area ) but lets leave that part for now.

My code now looks something like this:

```
img="the 45 squares ime in the provided link"
imgcorner = ImageCorners[img, MaxFeatures -> (45*4)];
HighlightImage[img, imgcorner ]
```

I get points on the corners of the squares in the given image, but my problem is in the fact that `ImageCorners` gives the output is ranked by decreasing measure of corner strength and I don't know how to organize the data in a more meaningful way.

Comment: Take a look at `MorphologicalComponents[ ]` and `ComponentMeasurements[ ]`. Much easier to go from those

Comment: `boxes = image // Binarize // ColorNegate // ComponentMeasurements[#, "BoundingBox"][[All, 2]] &` followed by `Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle @@@ boxes}]` to verify the result.